# What is critical edge spliting used for?

Tags: llvm, compiler-optimization, ssa

In llvm IR's phi elimination, before adding move instructions to eliminate phi instructions, we need to split the cirtical edge. I don't know what the process of spliting critical edge is used for exactly.

In some online or book sources, the edge spliting is for avoiding the lost of copy problem or ensure the correctness of elimination of phi instructions. However I have read from the tiger book that the spliting edges can have some other advantages.